# Reference text location with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now I'm working to insert a new element in an old template and I'm having some issues. Basically there area  bunch of already defined css rules elsewhere that make it very difficult for me to exactly position my divs as I would like.

Is it possible to somehow reference a div that represents the location where the text is actually rendered? I don't actually care much if the solution is in javascript or css, but logically css seems like the right location for this feature.

Example:

```
<div>
    <div style="text-align:right">Content</div>
</div>
```

In that example there would be a large div spanning the width of the page, but I really only want something that directly deals with the comparatively small area in which the text actually exists. Is this possible?

Specifically what I'm looking to do is ensure that a new type of element I'm adding to an existing template (think navigation tabs) will be extremely modular. I'd like to be able to use very different description lengths for these tabs and be able to apply backgrounds to them without prior knowledge of their DOM parents (I can put anything new within them, but the current layout means this would have to work within some random div and also within some random span)

Comment: I think you can do this using jQuery.

Comment: CSS can only affect elements. You can wrap the text in a `<span>` or something. It would help if you'd describe exactly what it is you want to do, because your assumption that you need this ability may be inaccurate.

Comment: @Pointy Fair point, updated with more specific use-case

Comment: @ShuklaJay I would be more than happy to use jQuery for this, I'm just not sure how exactly I would do this in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel deeply silly about this, but I'm going to go ahead and post this answer in case somebody else searches this in the future. jQuery in fact has a trivial solution for this.

Example:

```
<div>
    <div id="id" style="text-align-right">Some Text</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").wrapInner("<span id=renderedTextWrapper" />);
    $("#renderedTextWrapper").//do whatever you want with it
}
```

Once you've got that element it's pretty easy to do whatever you like. To get around the issue of having to insert this into random DOM locations I just wrapped my text in a div and made sure it wasn't escaped when it was passed to the template.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot position something in against the text inside an html element, only against the element itself.

You could however (if you want to go this far) calculate the size of the element, find its positioning and its text alignment and do math to figure out where to put your newly inserted element.  You could theoretically count the characters in the element, get their font size and calculate their length in pixels.  I can't demonstrate the calculations because you haven't provided your business rules

```
<div>
    <div style="text-align:right">Content</div>
</div>

<script>
function insertNewElement(element, newElement){ //element is a jquery object referencing the element you're inserting against and newElement is the one you're inserting

    var offset = element.offset()
    var alignmnet = element.css("text-align")
    var parent = element.parent(); 
    //now do the calculations you need to and adjust the newElement's css
    parent.append(newElement); 

}

</script>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this approach break if I resized the window or moved the text in anyway after rendering the page? Also consider my business rules flexible. I don't really care how the effect is achieved so long as it's robust enough to be inserted into some semi-arbitrary DOM location and still work.

Comment: not if you accounted for it.  you'd have to listen for the window to resize or an element to move then recalculate.  Since the original element is in the flow of the document and is in a sense your reference point you could write your calculations generically so that each time your FN was called it adjusted it correctly.  that said, its certainly a lot of work and you have to weigh the benefits

Comment: Eh, that's doable, I feel like there must be a solution that isn't this rickety though. I'm also dubious of the assertion that these calculations could actually been done robustly across browser. Could you put together an example of any sort?

Comment: Did some more digging. Glad to know that there was in fact a much easier way to do this.